# replace windows 8 with fedora 21

Tags: windows-8, fedora, fedora-21

Has anyone replaced their windows 8 pc with fedora 21 ? if yes,

1. is it advisable to do so? also,
2. did you have to disable secure boot or bootloader lock or both?

Comment: Use some up-to-date Fedora. 21 is already EOL and 24 is just behind the door.

Answer (score 0):

I'd back up first in case something went wrong. Recovery disks are always a good idea. 'Advisable' is opinion based, but far too many people linux, then panic when they want to go back.

I didn't need to disable secure boot - fedora has a signed bootloader and it just works. I did use a installer USB made with liveusbcreator, and I believe it installed in UEFI mode.